# Apache 2.4 .htaccess - Point All Requests to index.html With One Exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I currently have the following `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /production/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The web server's document root is currently the `/production` folder referenced in the above (the `.htaccess` file is in the parent folder since `/production` is deleted and rebuilt with every code commit).  The above will direct all traffic to my site to `index.html`.

I would like to make an exception to this.  If the request is `www.mydomain.com/specialrequest`, I would like a PHP script called `script.php` in the parent folder to run.

To review, this is my `/var/www/html` directory:

```
-html
    -production
    -anotherfolder
    -.htaccess
    -script.php
```

Apache is pointing to `/var/www/html/production` and I would like all requests to go to the `index.html` file in that directory unless the request is `/specialrequest` - in which case, I would like `script.php` to run.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache is pointing to `/var/www/html/production`

So, `/var/www/html/production` really is defined as the `DocumentRoot`. And so your `.htaccess` file is located *above* the document root. And the file you want to rewrite to (upon receiving this special request) is also above the document root.

Unfortunately, you can't rewrite to a file that is above the document root using `.htaccess` (regardless of where that `.htaccess` file is located). This is because the `RewriteRule` *substitution* in per-directory `.htaccess` files takes a **URL-path**, so trying to rewrite to a URL above the document root is simply invalid. If, however, you had access to the server config (or virtual host) then you could rewrite to a **filesystem path** (including above the document root) - instead of a URL-path - using this method.

So, `script.php` would need to be within the document root in order to be able to do this using `.htaccess`. In which case, you could do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exception
RewriteRule ^specialrequest$ /script.php [L]

# Front controller
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

But in this case, `script.php` is would need to be located at `/html/production/script.php` (in the document root), not at `/html/script.php` (above the document root) - as in your current filesystem structure.

Incidentally, the `RewriteBase /production/` directive in your `.htaccess` file is entirely superfluous. You're not using a relative path substitution anyway, but since `/production` is the *document root* then `/index.html` (a document root relative URL-path) will rewrite to `/production/index.html` anyway.

---

If, however, you could write this directly in your server config (or virtual host), then you could do what you require. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite to filesystem path (in the server config)
RewriteRule ^/specialrequest$ /var/www/html/script.php [L]

# Front controller
RewriteRule ^/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/. /index.html [L]
```